# java.lang.NullPointerException inside onAttachFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity

as usual I hope this is not a dumb question and I hope someone can help me out.

I can't reproduce this error in my phone or in my simulator so I'm not sure what's causing ti, but I'm getting some reports like the one below from the users on the Play Store.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.josie.myclass/com.josie.myclass.mainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3768)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.josie.myclass.mainActivity.onAttachFragment(mainActivity.java:183)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:830)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1805)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:200)
    at com.josie.myclass.mainActivity.onCreate(mainActivity.java:55)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
    ... 11 more
```

I've been struggling with this for a while and I can't fix it... The problem seems to be in my `onAttachFragment` method and in particular we're talking about line 183 of mainActivity.java

Here it is:

```
    @Override
        public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (fragment != null){
            super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
            if (fragment.getTag() != null){
                    if (fragment.getTag().equals("video_singolo")){
                                    mStacks.get(AppConstants.TAB_VIDEO).push(fragment);
                            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                            //Integer tabvideosize = mStacks.get(AppConstants.TAB_VIDEO).size();
                    } else if (fragment.getTag().equals("news_singola")){
                                    mStacks.get(AppConstants.TAB_NEWS).push(fragment);
                            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                            //Integer tabvideosize2 = mStacks.get(AppConstants.TAB_PIUVISTI).size();
                    } 
            }
            }

        }
```

As you can see I've added some `!= null` stuff to avoid pushing null fragments etc, but it still gives the error. Line 183 is this one:

```
mStacks.get(AppConstants.TAB_NEWS).push(fragment);
```

Thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: Must check that "news_singola" name is proper ??

Answer (score 1):

Either `mStacks` is null or `mStacks.get(AppConstants.TAB_NEWS)` is null.

Add the following check to your code:

```
if(mStacks!=null && mStacks.get(AppConstants.TAB_NEWS)!=null ) mStacks.get(AppConstants.TAB_NEWS).push(fragment);
```

Comment: A comment and and answer ? The comment was fine, as this doesn't really solve the problem ...

Comment: Hi, how do you know it did not solve the problem? I can remove the comment